# Timing function for inner.html in 3 second intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I want to create two variable functions and then activate them after a three seconds.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  let year2 = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = "2+ years"
    }, 3000);
  }
  let year3 = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = "3+ years"
    }, 6000);
  }
  let scrollOne = scroll > 20;

  if (scrollOne) {
    year2();
  } else {
    year3();
  }
});
```

Comment: and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: `window.scroll` executes your function und you return it another function. What should it do with that?

Comment: Looks like you need to call your functions instead of returning them.

Comment: @JLRishe too funny, we had the same wording :)

Comment: It should activate the functions after scrolling down to more than 200 @Stephan

Comment: @SourceOverflow I need it to change text within 3 second intervals

Comment: But why is it triggered by scroll? That will repeatedly call it, unless you manually check it. What is the context? And again 'and what exactly is your problem?' That means, what works as intended, what doesn't, what do you want to happen instead? Also an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/degeziloki/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @SourceOverflow I am new at JavaScript. Please excuse me. The inner.html will be displayed but my timing function does not.

Comment: Excuse me. It does work but year3 does not show up after the milliseconds

Comment: @SourceOverflow Here is A JSBIN example:     
jsbin.com/degeziloki/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: In that JSBIN, I don't see anything that wold resemble what your code makes me think what you want. Please clarify in simple steps: e.g. `1) User scrolling down more than 20px triggers timer 2) when the timer is finished change that text. There should at most be one timer active...`. Basically tell us your requirements, then tell us, what exactly does and doesn't work. I'm sorry that I am that insistent, but without a good question, we can't provide a good answer. And frankly, good (basic) questions about html, css, js are generally answered within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call your methods instead of returning them:

```
if (scrollOne) {
    year2();
} 
else {
    year3();
}
```

I removed `(year2 = true)` year2 is a method, it won't be true, but it will always be defined

Comment: Thank you, it works for year2() but not after 3 seconds for year3()

Comment: seems like scrollOne is alway true?

Comment: Yes, but I would like for it to just activate the year2() and year3()